# What's wrong to receipt validation flow with SKReceiptRefreshRequest

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

We use Server Side Receipt validation for IAPs (auto-renewable subscriptions) integration in the app. We want users to subscribe with the introductory prices first.

Users click a special banner "Get Premium", and before app shows the window with subscription options, we check user's eligibility for Introductory offers, which is:

1. verify whether the receipt is presented on the app
2. if it's not, we use `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` method to load the receipt
3. the iTunes Auth dialogue is fired, if it's SandBox environment
4. once user authenticated, continue to the validation flow on the server, else show an error "Please sign in to iTunes to continue"

**Our expectations:**

Apple review team should provide a password and authenticate within the iTunes Authentication dialogue to continue with testing.

**The issue:**

Apple review team *Cancels* the iTunes Auth dialogue, gets an error from our app and rejects our app reporting "Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness".

**Recommendation within the resolution center:**

> When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used in production," you should validate against the test environment instead.

**Relevant resource we used for reference:**

[After I install the development app with Xcode, the appStoreReceiptURL is nil. What is the proper way to handle this situation?](http://0016228-CH1-RECEIPT-AFTER_I_INSTALL_THE_DEVELOPMENT_APP_WITH_XCODE__THE_APPSTORERECEIPTURL_IS_NIL__WHAT_IS_THE_PROPER_WAY_TO_HANDLE_THIS_SITUATION_)

*We've been struggling with this problem for several rejections. We followed all the recommendations mentioned in the reference, official guidelines and resolution center with no idea of the reason of these rejections. All help is appreciated.*

Answer (score 0):

We also got rejected by the review team because they cancel the login prompt when our app checks the receipt with `SKReceiptRefreshRequest`.

We were able to pass the review by making a test Apple ID account and provide that as part of the submission, so the review team uses it to log in. The test account should either be invited to Testflight already or is a sandbox account.